# How to change an existing application to use email as sign in credentials?

Tags: c#, authentication, authorization, openid-connect, asp.net-core-6.0

I have an ASP.NET Core 6.0 application as well as a [SPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) application. Both consume one API and are clients of an OIDC IdentityProvider.

Currently, users are beginning to log in using their usernames. It is a username in the default ASP.NET Identity Model. I want to change the application to use email as log in credentials as well as to make the usernames nonunique.

I've stumbled upon the problem that the username in the model is supposed to be unique and that is non-customizable behaviour. What are the ways to make the username nonunique as well as allow users to log in using email. Are there any common approaches to this problem?

I haven't tried much. I've found out that username in ASP.NET identity model is unique, which is what I don't want. I don't have much experience in backend side, thus asked the question early.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What are the ways to make the username nonunique as well as allow
> users to log in using email. Are there any common approaches to this
> problem?

Yes, you are right. In asp.net core Identity, the IdentityUser's UserName is unique, and we can't modify it.

To your question, you can add a custom property to store the non-unique username, such as DisplayName, and let this property non-unique. Then, to allow user login using email, you should make the email as unique. After that change the login page to use email login and set the UserName and DisplayName. Refer to the following sample.

1. Create a Asp.net Core application and use [Scaffold Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio) to add the identity pages: Register, Login pages.

   From the Register.cshtml.cs page, we can see it will use the SetUserNameAsync and
   SetEmailAsync method to set the user's UserName and Email, and by default the email and UserName are same.

   ```
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/");
        ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = CreateUser();

            await _userStore.SetUserNameAsync(user, Input.Email, CancellationToken.None);
            await _emailStore.SetEmailAsync(user, Input.Email, CancellationToken.None);
            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);
   ```

   If create user, the result as below:
   [image]
2. [Add custom user data (DisplayName) to Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/add-user-data?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio).

   Create an ApplicationUser class to add the DisplayName:

   ```
    public class ApplicationUser:IdentityUser
    {
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }             
    }
   ```

   Add Dbset in the ApplicationDbContext:

   ```
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
    {
        public DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }
    }
   ```

   Change the Identity service in the Program.cs file:

   ```
    builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => {
        options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true; 
        options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true; //set email unique
    })
   ```

   In the _LoginPartial.cshtml and the Identity related pages, replaces the IdentityUser to ApplicationUser.

   After that enable migration to update the database:

   ```
    Add-migration AddDisplayName
    Update-database
   ```

   Then, the AspNetUsers table as below:

   [image]
3. Change the Register page to register the user with email and DisplayName

   In the Register.cshtml.cs file, add DisplayName property in the InputModel.

   [image]

   In the Register.cshtml page, add a textbox for the DisplayName property.

   [image]

   In the Register page OnPostAsync method, you can refer to the following code to set the UserName, DisplayName and Email.

   ```
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/");
        ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = CreateUser();

            user.DisplayName = Input.DisplayName;
            //generate a unique UserName.
            var uniqueusername = $"{Input.DisplayName}_{Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N")}";
            await _userStore.SetUserNameAsync(user, uniqueusername, CancellationToken.None);

            await _emailStore.SetEmailAsync(user, Input.Email, CancellationToken.None);

            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);
   ```

   In the Login page OnPostAsync method:

   use the UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(String) Method method to find the user first, then use the SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(TUser, String, Boolean, Boolean) method to login.

   ```
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/");

        ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(Input.Email);

            if (user !=null)
            { 
                // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
                // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, set lockoutOnFailure: true
                var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
                    return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
                }
   ```

   The result as below:

   [image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer. Actually, I've already decided to store email in the username identity field too and create displayName property. I don't know whether it is better or worse in terms of best practice than the approach with GUID that you've suggested.

Comment: Both methods are very similar, the only difference is that set different values in the Register page OnPostAsync  method. So, you can use either one of them.